# Pos/Neg Number Mask in Ext.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net, mask, ext.net, maskedtextbox

I've got a mask on a TextField in Ext.Net with the following to capture positive integers, including those with commas.

```
MaskRe="/[0-9\,]/"
```

I only just realized that this doesn't allow for negatives.  After trying various combinations of `MaskRe`s and searching Google, I've got nothing.

How can I change the mask to allow for positive and negative values?

Note: I would *not* allow the user to enter a plus sign (+) for positive values.

Answer (score 1):

Finally got it working!  I ended up going with this:

```
MaskRe="[\-0123456789\,]"
```